# Deletar dados de um db usando sqlite3 e bottle (python)

Tags: python, sqlite3, bottle

Estou tentando fazer, utilizando o framework BottlePy, um CRUD no formato ToDo (como no exemplo mostrado na própria documentação do bottle https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial_app.html). Até o momento as funções de adicionar item e alterar item está funcionando bem. A minha dúvida é na função delete. A imagem a seguir resume meu código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clico no botão delete da minha lista, sou redirecionado para o link  local host do item selecionado (http://localhost:8080/delete2) e tenho o seguinte retorno na página:

Error: 500 Internal Server Error
Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:8080/delete2' caused an error:
Internal Server Error

Exception:
ValueError('parameters are of unsupported type')

Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jonathan/dev/bottle01/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/home/jonathan/dev/bottle01/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1740, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "svr.py", line 50, in delete_item
    cur.execute ('DELETE FROM todo WHERE id = ?', (nu))
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

O problema é: Não estou conseguindo fazer o botão delete deletar o item selecionado. A ideia era fazer uma espécie de alert box para deletar o item da lista ToDo. Desde já, agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Boa noite Jonathan! Pergunta o ? em python é uma variável, pois no log está dizendo que o parametro não é suportado, pode ser o (nu) no final da expressão, ou pode ser o ?.

Comment: Boa noite, Denis! Então o nu é apenas uma variável. Como na imagem que mandei o 

<!-- BOTAO DELETE -->
<a href="/delete{{row[0]}}" class="ver no bootstrap" onClick="return confirm('Voce deseja deletar?')" >Delete</a>

check box abre após eu apertar a opção delete que fica localizado ao lado do item que quero deletar, em uma página html.
Quando aperto ok neste check box ele me retorna o um endereço delete e o id do item. 
No outro código, o código de rotas, eu tento pegar este id como a variável nu e depois na hora de deletar eu chamo o valor nu, ou seja, o id gerado pelo meu check box.

Comment: Uma outra observação. Acho que um dos meus problemas é que o nu esta sendo interpretado como str e eu preciso que ele seja int.